# Rails 4 Video Conferencing Solution / Gem / Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, video-conferencing, webinar

I am looking for a video conferencing option for my rails app.  I am not looking for what is better or what is best as I know that is opinionated.  My needs are specific so I hope there is a specific solution.

1. The video conferencing must be compatible for "all" browser types so WebRTC isn't an option.
2. It also has to be flexible enough to not take up the whole screen.  My users will need to use other screen space to enter information.
3. Multiple users must be able to sign in to a single video session as to create a webinar or larger conference (not a deal breaker if this option is not available)

I have tried VLine, Skype, and oovoo so far but none match the criteria above.  Price is not necessarily an issue but, of course, I'd prefer something that has a free tier or is open source.  I am open to building my own if there is decent guidance/tutorials on how to do so.

I've noticed that other similar questions have been closed so I'm hoping that my criteria/needs will make this a legitimate question for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Tokbox's OpenTok](http://tokbox.com/)?

1. Their 1.0 specification uses flash and supports Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari with native iOS support as well, you won't find a cross platform currently that doesn't use flash.
2. You can specify a size in the plugin.
3. You can allow for people to subscribe to streams that others have published and are broadcasting etc.

Comment: That is an excellent recommendation given my criteria and constraints. Thank you John!

Comment: This would mean subscribing to Tokbox right? Can I use OpenTok only my own server and not pay TokBox for it?

Comment: Well you can use tokbox to do peer to peer video conferencing without their servers, but their framework falls back to theirs when there are problems. Other solutions exist but any webrtc framework this developed that has ios and android clients isn't going to be free.